# whats wrong with my following code?I a, trying to make a Sudoku board but It is not showing any textfield in the panel.what could be the reason?

Tags: java, swing

whats wrong with my following code?I am new to java and I am trying to make a Sudoku board using java Jframe and panel,but when i run it It is not showing any textfield in the panel .what could be the reason?

```
    package sudoku;

    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

     class sudokuframe extends JFrame
    {
        int grid_size=9;
        int sub_size=3;
        public int cell_size=60;
        public int canvas_height=cell_size*grid_size;
        public int canvas_width=cell_size*grid_size;

        public JTextField[][] cell=new JTextField[grid_size][grid_size];

        //public int puzzle[][];/*=new int[grid_size][grid_size];*/
        //public boolean flag[][]=new boolean[grid_size][grid_size];

    public int puzzle[][]={{5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2},
               {6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8},
               {1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7},
               {8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3},
               {4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1},
               {7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6},
               {9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4},
               {2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5},
               {3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9}};

    public boolean flag[][]=
               {{false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false},
               {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false}};
public  sudokuframe()
    {
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(grid_size,grid_size));
        System.out.println("inside constructor");
        for(int row=0;row<grid_size;row++)
        {
            for(int column=0;column<grid_size;column++)
            {
                cell[row][column]=new JTextField();
                panel.add(cell[row][column]);
                if(flag[row][column])
                {
                    cell[row][column].setText(puzzle[row][column]+"");
                    cell[row][column].setEditable(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    cell[row][column].setText("");
                    cell[row][column].setEditable(true);    
                }

            }
        }

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(canvas_height,canvas_width));
        panel.setVisible(true);
        pack();


    }

}

 public class sudoku
 {
     public static void  main(String arg[])
     {

         sudokuframe frame=new sudokuframe();
         frame.setSize(900,900);
         frame.setVisible(true);

     }
 }
```

Comment: You never add panel to your JFrame; so nothing added to it will show anywhere.

Comment: Get rid of `panel.setVisible(true);` as it does nothing of use, and instead have something useful like: `add(panel);` since this will actually add the panel JPanel to the JFrame.

Comment: how i can add borders or highlight the internal sub-grids?

Comment: @kamalpreetkaur, See [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

Comment: my problem is i have not made nine panels for all sub cubes ,so how i can color them and provide borders to cells by grouping them as a cube/panel.as border will be applicable to panel only